# VRExpansionPlugin New Level Can't teleport

Tags: virtual-reality, unreal-engine4

I'm using the VRExpansionPlugin in UnrealEngine 4. 
Steps I've taken

- Created a new "Default" level within the template project provided by the VRExpansionPlugin.
- Added a NavMeshBoundsVolume to the level.
- Deleted the existing "Player Start" and replaced it with the "VRPlayer Start".

I would expect that when I "Play" the level I should be able to point at the ground and teleport around, but instead I just see the short blue teleport line that almost immediately cuts off.

I know that I am missing a step (probably only one) but I'm not sure what step I am missing. Also, I can't find any documentation to help figure out what I am missing. So, with that said, what am I missing to enable teleport movement in my UE4 VRExpansionPlugin VR project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out to be both something weird and very simple. I was comparing it to a "Default" level I had created in the past that worked and I noticed that on my previous working example my navmesh was halfway into the floor instead of sitting on top. The navmesh on my current level was position by raising it above the floor and using the "end" key to tell it sit exactly on top of the floor, which for some reason caused the teleportation to not work. I moved the navmesh down into the floor and everything started working perfectly.

tl;dr; The answer is to make sure the navmesh is not sitting exactly on top of the floor but instead below or inside it.